# Subdomain and subdirectories together in one installation

Tags: multisite, installation, domain, configuration, customization

I'm currently want to develop my design company website and choosing wordpress as my CMS.

How do I should install the wordpress when I want the domain structure like this:

- Blog = blog.example.com
- Portfolio = example.com/portfolio/...
- Shop = shop.example.com = using WooCommerce

I'll be glad if someone would help, because I really have no idea to config.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want sections in a subdomain *and* in subdirectories, use a multi-site installation. See [Create a Network](http://codex.wordpress.org/Create_A_Network) and our tag [multi-site](/questions/tagged/multi-site).

Then you set the the blog and the shop as separate sites, and the `portfolio` as a custom post type or as a regular page in the main blog.